# thread1: Program received signal " EXC_bad_Access"

Tags: iphone

I have an erro in the line NSLog(@"  %@",self.myMutableDictionnaire); thread1: Program received signal " EXC_bad_Access".

please, i have passed one hour but i could not fixe the problem.
what can be the reason oy my crash.

thanks.

Comment: Please post some code , so that we can give some solution to you...

Comment: Also, use NSZombieEnabled to debug this kind of errors!

Answer (score 1):

try to retain "myMutableDictionnaire" when you are assigning the values in it

Answer (score 0):

I realized that what I wrote doesn't make sense, it seems that a value has been assigned, and not retained or copied as Saurabh says

Comment: Re: "It is likely that myMutableDictionnaire doesn't exist." => why would that cause a crash?

Comment: True, it would be nil, and the NSLog would'nt crash, my bad.